# Koma-Script: How to reduce the size of the footer

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I'd like to reduce the size of the footer in the following example, because I want to get rid of the extra whitespace area under the footer.

```
\documentclass[a4page]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ihead[left head]{left head} 
\ohead[2010/11]{2010/11}
\ifoot[\today]{\today}

\cfoot[Authors]{Authors} 

\setheadsepline{.4pt}
\setfootsepline{.4pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Text...
\end{document}
```

Can this be accomplished somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to modify the page layout. For instance, based on your example, adding

```
\usepackage[bottom=10em]{geometry}
```

to just after the `\documentclass`, the footer appears much lower. You can tweak the geometry options (either at package load or at the beginning of the document via `\geometry{...}`) to suit your needs. There may also be other options by setting this manually. For ease of explanation, consider reading the [`fancyhdr` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) [documentation](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

[image: Footer/page layout modifications via the geometry package]